# Unable to scan the final briefcase

Tags: watch-dogs

I can not scan the final briefcase in Watch_Dogs. I have seen plenty of videos of people scanning that case, but none of them played on a PC. I am talking about this briefcase:

[image]
[image]

Was anyone on a PC been able to scan this briefcase? I am able to scan the mobile phone on the table, but not the briefcase. Restarting the game changed nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this seems to be a bug in the game. This was not the last briefcase, there was another briefcase icon on the map that I had missed. There, I was able to scan another briefcase (my tenth) which unlocked the final mission of human traffic. I guess I scanned that "unscannable" briefcase before and the game just "forgot" to remove the marker. Strange bug.